# Generate 2 different list in one foreach loop with powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

I stucked in foreach part.I couldn't find any solution for generating 2 different lists in one foreach loop.I used 2 foreach but it didn't help.Below side I shared my desire output.

My code:

```
$InStuff = @'
a
b
c
'@.Split("`n").Trim()

$InStuff2 = @'
1
2
3
'@.Split("`n").Trim()

$SPart_1 = 'application="'
$SPart_2 = ' path='
$SPart_3 = ' name='
$SPart_4 = ' application'

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff) {
    foreach ($IS2_Item in $InStuff2) {    
        $UName = $IS_Item 

        $UName2 = $IS2_Item

        $Sentence = -join (
            $SPart_1, $UName,
            $SPart_2, $UName2,
            $SPart_3, $UName2,
            $SPart_4
        )
        ''
        $Sentence
    }
}
```

Fail output :

```
application="a path=1 name=1 application

application="a path=2 name=2 application

application="a path=3 name=3 application

application="b path=1 name=1 application

application="b path=2 name=2 application

application="b path=3 name=3 application

application="c path=1 name=1 application

application="c path=2 name=2 application

application="c path=3 name=3 application
```

My desire output :

```
application="a path=1 name=1 application

application="b path=2 name=2 application

application="c path=3 name=3 application
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `for` loop:

```
$InStuff = @'
a
b
c
'@.Split("`n").Trim()

$InStuff2 = @'
1
2
3
'@.Split("`n").Trim()

$SPart_1 = 'application="'
$SPart_2 = ' path='
$SPart_3 = ' name='
$SPart_4 = ' application'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InStuff.count; $i++) {
        $Sentence = -join (
            $SPart_1, $InStuff[$i],
            $SPart_2, $InStuff2[$i],
            $SPart_3, $InStuff2[$i],
            $SPart_4
        ), ''
        $Sentence
}
```

This will likely go wrong if your input arrays are not the same length, so it is not that safe. Perhaps using a hash or custom object would be a better idea:

```
$arr = @()
$arr += new-object PSCustomObject -property @{application='a';path=1;name=1}
$arr += new-object PSCustomObject -property @{application='b';path=2;name=2}
$arr += new-object PSCustomObject -property @{application='c';path=3;name=3}

$arr | % { 'application="{0} path={1} name={2}' -f $_.application, $_.path, $_.name }
```

Answer (score 0):

@arco444 is right, no matter what you will have problems if your lists are different lengths. You should reconsider how you are collecting and formatting the data. Here is an alternative method:

```
$InStuff = "a","b","c"
$InStuff2 = 1,2,3
$listCount = $InStuff.Count
$x = 0
do {
    $strOut = "application= `"path = {0} name = {1} application`"" -f $InStuff[$x], $InStuff2[$x]
    $strOut
    $x++
}
while ( $x -lt $listCount )
```

Not sure what you want with a stray `"` in there, I've added one to enclose the output:

```
application= "path = a name = 1 application"
application= "path = b name = 2 application"
application= "path = c name = 3 application"
```

If you plan to use this output for further processing by PowerShell, like putting it in a csv with `Export-Csv` then you should forgo the `application` text and create an object instead:

```
$InStuff = "a","b","c"
$InStuff2 = 1,2,3
$listCount = $InStuff.Count
$x = 0

do {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        path = $InStuff[$x]
        name = $InStuff2[$x]
    }
    $x++
}
while ( $x -lt $listCount )
```

While that's not exactly what you are asking for, it's been my experience that data in this format is far more useful:

```
path name
---- ----
a       1
b       2
c       3
```

you can add lines to

```
    [pscustomobject]@{
        path = $InStuff[$x]
        name = $InStuff2[$x]
    }
```

for the additional text (if it's a must) and do something like this:

```
    [pscustomobject]@{
        type = "application"
        path = $InStuff[$x]
        name = $InStuff2[$x]
    }
```

and that will add a column for the word `application`

Comment: ty brendan ;) appreciate it